# Requesting data from GA by GET request with API key fails

Tags: google-analytics-api

On http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ I compose a request to GA which also works on there. The URL I end up with looks as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga%3A12345678&metrics=ga%3Avisitors
  &start-date=2013-11-19&end-date=2013-12-03&max-results=50
```

Now if I understand the the [following paragraph](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys) correctly ...

> If your client application does not use OAuth 2.0, then it must
>   include an API key when it calls an API that's enabled within a Cloud
>   Console project. The application passes this key into all API requests
>   as a key=API_key parameter.

... then I just have to append the Server API key which I generated on Google Cloud Console like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga%3A12345678&metrics=ga%3Avisitors
  &start-date=2013-11-19&end-date=2013-12-03&max-results=50
  &key=AI[...]TE
```

and I should receive a JSON with the data. But instead I receive an error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required",
  "message":"Login Required","locationType":"header",
  "location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

**What is my mistake or misconception here?**

---

What you would like to do is to request data from GA via its API by using only the API key and not having to resort to external libraries except for Curl to implement GET/POST requests. That it is possible to get this done only using an API key I know because this is what Pentaho Kettle does.

Comment: Have u tried your query with http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ First?

Comment: @Kamran: That's what I mean by writing "... which also works on there." The last version using the key I cannot try there of course.

Comment: oh i missed it. I used .net and there API v3 to get data from google analytics. I used there keyfile.Don't know how to use it in Curl

Comment: curl is a library which facilitates all sorts of network communication. in that sense I mentioned curl merely to emphasize my intention to not use any libraries beyond this. The URLs have been tested simply in a browser as at that point I am not aware of a reason why this should fail.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Analytics API cannot be used without an authorized/authenticated user. Although your "application" may not use OAuth 2.0 for authentication and authorization, you still need to authorize/authenticate somehow, and an API Key does not do that.

If you read the rest of that document you linked to, specifically [Keys, access, security, and identity](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys) you'll see it mentions that API Keys are not for Authorization. Also, take a look at [Choosing an Auth Mechanism](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/GettingStarted) to see what options are available for authentication.

That line

> If your client application does not use OAuth 2.0, then it must
>   include an API key..

is referring to the case where the authentication mechanism you've used is not OAuth 2.0 but something else like OAuth 1.0, AuthSub, or ClientLogin (which are all deprecated). In those cases you need to include the API Key so that your API requests can be associated properly with your Cloud Console project.

You may want to review the [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization) document for the Google Analytics Core Reporting API.

If you want to use CURL to make requests then you'll need to send an Access Token with each request.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further where you got the information for your first paragraph where you state, that you can't use Google Analytics API with only an API Key? I want to make an app which connects to my own Google Analytics account so the users shouldn't have to sign into their own accounts.

Comment: This information is available in the documentation. OAuth 2.0 is required. Any of the API you look at have an Authorization page that explains this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization

Even in your scenario you are still authorizing a user (yourself in this case) to access the API and request data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at using the google-analytics-super-proxy

This will allow you to create end points to pull data.
The super proxy will deal with the auth, and your applications can just use the end points to fetch the required data

ref:https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy